# Why does Touma care if other people learn that magic exists?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

There are multiple scenes in the Index movie (The Miracle of Endymion) where Touma cuts Index off when she's about to say something to Arisa about magic or magicians or whatnot.

Why does Touma have an interest in preventing Arisa (or anyone) from learning that magic exists? It doesn't seem like other people knowing about magic would have any adverse effects on him.

Comment: Probably to prevent them from stepping into the world of science-magic conflict that he has experienced so far?

Comment: I personally think he might want to avoid of those conflict between Science and Magic ( since It is already happened and happen along with anime )

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, Touma doesn't want everyone to know about the truth of Academy City, where corruption prevails and everyone is just a test subject. If everyone knows the truth, all chaos would break loose.

And once people learn about magic, the domino effect happens.

People learn about magic -> People learn about the struggle of power (Science vs Magic) -> People learn that Academy City is corrupted beyond belief in every aspect possible -> A big war ensues where everyone chooses a side

Just think about the magic side as a gang that is trying to take control of the government. The government (Academy City) has been sweeping their own dirty deeds under the rug, as well as concealing their opponents. Learning about magic opens the door to everything.